# apt looking for i386 files, even though architecture is amd64

Tags: apt, repository

I am trying to use a file repository for updating Ubuntu GNU/Linux on a non-connected machine. The architecture for this machine (uname -a):

```
x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The results of `dpkg --print-architecture` are:

```
amd64
```

It is a Trusty Tahr amd64 machine, and it specifically says this, for example, in the aptitude sources.list file. Also, the "About this Computer" in ubuntu specifically says the machine is 64-bit. So, I installed the amd64 packages on the machine. However, when I try to do `apt-get update`, I get errors such as:

```
W: Failed to fetch file:/var/spool/apt-mirror-trusty/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  File not found
```

So, in other words, even though it is a 64-bit machine, apt is inexplicably trying to read i386 packages. Why is it doing this and how can I make it use the 64-bit packages?

Note that there is nothing in sources.list that specifies i386.

The only uncommented line in the sources.list file is:

```
deb file:///var/spool/apt-mirror-trusty/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

On Ubuntu `amd64` installations, `i386` is enabled as an additional architecture by default. `apt` & co. expect repositories to provide all configured architectures, which causes the error you're seeing.

Since your mirror only has `amd64` packages, you should mark it as such:

```
deb [ arch=amd64 ] file:///var/spool/apt-mirror-trusty/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` will show any architecture for which multiarch support is enabled; I had the same problem and (probably unsurprisingly) the above command reported: `i386`

Comment: This doesn't explain how to disable additional architecture *by default*. Putting  `[arch=amd64]` to each `deb` line is not a good solution. This explains how to do it: https://superuser.com/a/714392/376867

Comment: @midenok Where did I suggest adding an arch qualifier to every repository descriptor? Completely disabling `i386` to deal with one troublesome repository is rather overkill. Note that if you have multiple repositories causing the problem described in the question, that indicates a problem with the repositories’ [Architectures field](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format#Architectures), not with the local configuration.