# Apt repositories. How 'Architectures' option works. How to determine which value may be used?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, ansible

I am using ansible to set up two apt repositories on my Ubuntu_22.04 nodes.

In ansible there is a var called {{ ansible_architecture }} which gives: `aarch64` in this case.

I used it to set up two repos for podman and docker using [DEB822 Source Format](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/sources.list.5.en.html#THE_DEB_AND_DEB-SRC_TYPES:_OPTIONS).
These are .sources files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`:

```
X-Repolib-Name: podman
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/podman.asc
URIs: https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:kubic:libcontainers:unstable/xUbuntu_22.04
Suites: /
Architectures: aarch64
Enabled: yes
Types: deb
```

```
X-Repolib-Name: docker
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc
URIs: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu
Suites: jammy
Components: stable
Architectures: aarch64
Enabled: yes
Types: deb
```

Podman repo works fine but docker repo require `arm64`

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/binary-aarch64/Packages' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'aarch64'
```

So my questions is how to figure out what keyword I can use to specify the architecture because podman accepts `aarch64` but docker requrire `arm64`. [Docker page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcpN5.png) suggests that both name should be correct but its the only thing I have found. Can it be determined just by having a URI like https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/ or is it only known to someone who configured it and I need to hit and miss?

Answer (score 2):

In Debian derivatives, the architecture name for 64-bit ARM is [`arm64`](https://wiki.debian.org/Arm64Port) (see also [dpkg-deb treats my architecture as amd64 instead of x86-64](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/667735/86440)), so that should be the value used. You can confirm this for any given repository by looking inside the relevant distribution directory in the repository (for example, [here for Docker](https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/mantic/stable/)) or in the “Architectures” entry in the repository’s `Release` file ([here for Docker](https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/mantic/Release)).

In most cases you don’t need to specify the “Architectures” entry in repository configuration files anyway. `apt` will automatically fetch the architecture matching the system’s architecture.

The main reason to specify “Architectures” is on systems configured with multiple architectures and repositories that don’t support all those architectures; see [apt looking for i386 files, even though architecture is amd64](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/272908/86440).